# Question for applescript with dragon Dictate

Tags: applescript, search, voice

I want to make a program that will take the question I ask it, input it to WolframAlpha, take the answer, convert it to text and the say the text.

```
    set defaultAnswer to ""
set cancelButton to "Cancel"
set buttonResearch to “ReSearch”

display dialog "Query: " default answer defaultAnswer buttons {cancelButton, buttonResearch} default button buttonResearch cancel button cancelButton with icon 1
copy the result as list to {button_pressed, text_returned}

if (button_pressed is buttonResearch) and (text_returned is not "") then

    open location "http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=" & my encode_text(text_returned, true, false)

    set a to "http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i="
    set b to my encode_text(text_returned, true, false)
    set c to a & b

    set myFile to (POSIX path of (path to temporary items)) & "curl_file.xml"
    do shell script "curl -L " & c & " -o " & myFile


end if

-- encoding high-ASCII characters:
on encode_char(this_char)
    set the ASCII_num to (the ASCII number this_char)
    set the hex_list to {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}
    set x to item ((ASCII_num div 16) + 1) of the hex_list
    set y to item ((ASCII_num mod 16) + 1) of the hex_list
    return ("%" & x & y) as string
end encode_char

-- TEXT ENCODING: encode spaces and high-level ASCII characters (those above 127)
-- encode_URL_A = encode most of the special characters reserved for use by URLs.
on encode_text(this_text, encode_URL_A, encode_URL_B)
    set the standard_characters to "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    set the URL_A_chars to "$+!'/?;&@=#%><{}[]\"~`^\\|*"
    set the URL_B_chars to ".-_:"
    set the acceptable_characters to the standard_characters
    if encode_URL_A is false then set the acceptable_characters to the acceptable_characters & the URL_A_chars
    if encode_URL_B is false then set the acceptable_characters to the acceptable_characters & the URL_B_chars
    set the encoded_text to ""
    repeat with this_char in this_text
        if this_char is in the acceptable_characters then
            set the encoded_text to (the encoded_text & this_char)
        else
            set the encoded_text to (the encoded_text & encode_char(this_char)) as string
        end if
    end repeat
    return the encoded_text
end encode_text
```

How do i access the temporary file?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just dictate into spotlight or google using Apple dictation?

Comment: Show us your attempts.

Comment: Well my attempts have gotten me nowhere... I tried a display dialog but it would not let me input through dictate, only typing

Comment: Apple's dictation works in a display dialog. It also works in spotlight though.

Comment: Froggard, i'm using Dragon Dictate

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to use Apple's dictation? Some clarification would be nice.

Comment: Well seeing as Dragon Dictate is way better i'm not sure why you need clarification... It has individual voice profiles, better voice recognition, and it's easier to program with

Comment: Well, apparently it isn't perfect given the fact that you're having trouble doing something that is trivial to do with Apple's dictation software. I suggest diversifying your voice recognition software somewhat. Dragon I'm sure works well for many situations, but what you're trying to do is going to be difficult doing it the way you're trying to do it. Apple's dictation is quite good these days, assuming you have Yosemite. I can write a script for you that uses Apple's voice recognition, but I can't do it with Dragon. Again though, since it's system-wide, you wouldn't even need a script.

Comment: The problem is not that it can't do it, it's that it can't execute a script and take voice input at the same time, since I need the input during the script... Which dictate can't do either... If you don't know how to write for Dragon why are you here? My question says "Dragon Dictate"....

Btw, Dragon uses applescript, automator etc. so its the same as dictate

Comment: I'm here to help you find a solution, one that you don't seem interested in. It's actually interested to note that the technology behind Dragon and Siri/Apple voice recognition are related. Both are from Nuance. If you want me to write a script for you that can do what you want, then I will. If you're not interested in finding a solution for your problem, then I will not. Good day.

Comment: All I'm saying is that you seem to be trying to steer me away from dragon but I have over 30hrs of commands coded into it so that's not even an option... I will appreciate any help but it will need to work with Dragon

Comment: Thank you, that was the clarification I asked for from the beginning.

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion

Answer (score 1):

This does the query part. The encoding routines are from https://macosxautomation.com :

```
set defaultAnswer to "Albert Einstein"
set cancelButton to "Cancel"
set buttonResearch to "ReSearch"

display dialog "Query: " default answer defaultAnswer buttons {cancelButton, buttonResearch} default button buttonResearch cancel button cancelButton with icon 1
copy the result as list to {button_pressed, text_returned}

if (button_pressed is buttonResearch) and (text_returned is not "") then

    open location "http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=" & my encode_text(text_returned, true, false)

end if

-- encoding high-ASCII characters:
on encode_char(this_char)
    set the ASCII_num to (the ASCII number this_char)
    set the hex_list to {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}
    set x to item ((ASCII_num div 16) + 1) of the hex_list
    set y to item ((ASCII_num mod 16) + 1) of the hex_list
    return ("%" & x & y) as string
end encode_char

-- TEXT ENCODING: encode spaces and high-level ASCII characters (those above 127)
-- encode_URL_A = encode most of the special characters reserved for use by URLs.
on encode_text(this_text, encode_URL_A, encode_URL_B)
    set the standard_characters to "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    set the URL_A_chars to "$+!'/?;&@=#%><{}[]\"~`^\\|*"
    set the URL_B_chars to ".-_:"
    set the acceptable_characters to the standard_characters
    if encode_URL_A is false then set the acceptable_characters to the acceptable_characters & the URL_A_chars
    if encode_URL_B is false then set the acceptable_characters to the acceptable_characters & the URL_B_chars
    set the encoded_text to ""
    repeat with this_char in this_text
        if this_char is in the acceptable_characters then
            set the encoded_text to (the encoded_text & this_char)
        else
            set the encoded_text to (the encoded_text & encode_char(this_char)) as string
        end if
    end repeat
    return the encoded_text
end encode_text
```

The problem to speak the result is not the speaking itself but to select the relevant parts. So better look for a tool that does that, or even better yet, use the website's services for that, often they have some sort of interface.

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm doing something wrong but
 1.) It shows the dialog box of what i did but then doesn't do anything else
 2.) When I try to change the "Please give me some input"to "What is your question?" it gives me an error

Comment: so does it does the query but not an output? Sorry i'm really new to this

Comment: I made the code minimalistic since you need results and not demos or teachings lol    Ok, this answer is basically just useful to compose the URL. We could use that URL to download the website so we don't have to open a browser. But to parse that and read the relevant parts…

Comment: Would you be able to help me out with that?